# How to require a custom JavaScript file from ExtJS package resources folder

Tags: javascript, extjs

I am creating a package for ExtJS 6 where I need to include an external JavaScript file as a resource.

I placed the file in the `resources` folder of my package, but I can't seem to find any documentation on how to use `Ext.require()` to load this file.

I could use `Ext.require(Ext.resolveResource("<@MyPackage>custom")` - that downloads and executes the `Sencha/build/production/MyApp/classic/resources/MyPackage/custom.js` but it also complains that it cannot load the class from this file:

```
[E] [Loader] The following classes failed to load:
[E] [Loader] Sencha/build/production/MyApp/classic/resources/MyPackage/custom from Sencha/build/production/MyApp/classic/resources/MyPackage/custom.js
```

Can `Ext.require()` be used for this purpose or do I have to use `Ext.AJAX` and create the `<script>` tag by myself?

Comment: Have you tried edition app.json?

Comment: Since I am creating a package, editing app.json seems wrong as it is outside the package code.

Comment: Are you creating a new class or overriding existing classes?

Comment: new components that extend Ext.Component.

Comment: IMO, you need to add the files as resource in app.json (after the ExtJS bundle, of course), so that you ExtJS can load you package at app start and you can use these class just like an existing class. Second option is that you can use `Ext.Loader`. However, I'd like to know other people's thoughts/opinions as well.

Answer (score 2):

Edit app.json and look for js property or add it in case it is not there.

```
...
"js": [
    {
        "path": "lib/myExternalLibrary.js",
        "includeInBundle": true
    },
]
...
```

reference https://docs.sencha.com/cmd/6.x/microloader.html#js

Comment: I was wondering if there is a way of doing this within the package, without requiring the app to be modified apart from the package reference.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe its already to late, but this works for ExtJs6 in your package.json

```
"js" : [{
    "path": "resources/js/OpenLayers.js",
    "bundle": true
}]
```